# Does continuous $g$ and integrable $f$ imply $g \circ f$ is integrable

Tags: integration, continuity, lebesgue-integral

Suppose we have a continuous function $g: R \to R$ and Lebesgue integrable function $f: R \to R$. Does it hold that $g \circ f$ is Lebesgue integrable ? If not, what addition assumptions required for the statement to hold ?

**Note:** I know it holds if domain($g$) and range($f$) are both restricted to some compact set, but I wish to know of other ways where both functions are allowed to take values in the entire space $R$.

Comment: What if $g$ is constant equal to $1$ ?

Comment: Some ideas (not rigorous), integrability of $f$ require $|f|\to 0$ at infinity, so we should have $g(x)\to 0$ at $x=0$ in a way that is integrable, i.e. setting $x=1/u$ we should have $g(1/u)$ integrable at infinity.

Answer (score -1):

Nope. On the positive axis we can for example take $f = 1/(1+x)^2$ and $g = \sqrt x$. Then $f$ has finite integral

**Note:** The same proof works on $\mathbb R$ by making both functions symmetric. Meaning define $f(-x) = f(x)$ for all $x >0$ and likewise for $g(x)$.

$$\int f d \mu = \lim_{a \to \infty} \int_0^a f(x) dx = \lim_{a \to \infty} \int_0^a \frac{1}{(1+x)^2} dx = \lim_{a \to \infty} \left( 1-\frac{1}{1+a} \right) = 1$$

but $gf(x) = 1/(1+x)$ has infinite integral.

$$\int f g d \mu = \lim_{a \to \infty} \int_0^a f(g(x)) dx = \lim_{a \to \infty} \int_0^a \frac{1}{1+x} dx = \lim_{a \to \infty} \log(1+a) = \infty$$

I suspect if $f$ and $g$ are both integrable then so is the composition.

Comment: Your given $g$ is not continuous on all of $\mathbb{R}$. Moreover, the original poster is asking for a proof that holds for all continuous functions $g: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, even ones that are not integrable on $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @MattE. Both of my functions are continuous.

Comment: @MattE. And my $g$ is not integrable either. I don't understand your objection.

Comment: "Both of my functions are continuous" well that's kinda true but your function is not defined on $\mathbb{R}$ (that's what Matt E probably trained to say).

Comment: @MarekKryspin See the note. You can just extend them to the whole line by symmetry.

Comment: My apologies, I'm still waking up. I see your note now about extending $g$ and $f$ to all of $\mathbb{R}$. You mean to use the functions $f(x) = \frac{1}{(1+ |x|)^2}$ and $g(x) = \sqrt{|x|}$.

Comment: I suspect you also want your example to show that $g\circ f$ is not integrable, instead of $f\circ g$. But that is also quickly amended.